# Multiple date listener

Tags: android, date

I have code like this

```
    private void Picker() {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar maxDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    maxDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    Calendar minDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    minDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    dataController = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
            controller.this,
            now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    );

    dataController.setMinDate(minDate);
    dataController.setMaxDate(maxDate);
    dataController.setTitle("Data awizacji");

    inputdataController.setFocusable(false);

    inputdataController.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            datadataController.show(getFragmentManager(), "Data");
        }
    });


    Calendar from = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar frommaxDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    frommaxDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    Calendar fromminDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    fromminDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    dataControllerSecond = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
            controller.this,
            from.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            from.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            from.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    );

   dataControllerSecond.setMinDate(fromminDate);
    dataControllerSecond.setMaxDate(frommaxDate);
    dataControllerSecond.setTitle("Data awizacji DO");

    inputdataControllerSecond.setFocusable(false);

    inputdataControllerSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dataControllerSecond.show(getFragmentManager(), "Data spotkania");
        }
    });

}


@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    now = Calendar.getInstance();
    now.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
inputdataController.setText(dateFormatter.format(now.getTime()));

    from = Calendar.getInstance();
    from.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
 inputdataControllerSecond.setText(dateFormatter.format(from.getTime()));
}
```

and I don't really know how to make two inputs independent of each other... I mean when im choosing one option from one of inputs it's choosing in all of them... I want to make two independent dates...
Did you know what did I wrong? I saw one question with answer that saying make another listener but I did, and it's still doesn't work correctly..
Im confused and I don't know how to make it...
It's so annoying for me... can someone help? :) (I don't need perfect code, I just need some clues what i did bad..)

Comment: Sounds like you need multiple on change listeners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable at the class level:

```
int type = 1;
```

and change your listeners:

```
inputdataController.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        type = 1;
        datadataController.show(getFragmentManager(), "Data");
    }
});
```

and

```
inputdataControllerSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        type = 2;
        dataControllerSecond.show(getFragmentManager(), "Data spotkania");
    }
});
```

then in `onDateSet()`

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    if (type == 1) {
        now = Calendar.getInstance();
        now.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        inputdataController.setText(dateFormatter.format(now.getTime()));
    } else if (type == 2) {
        from = Calendar.getInstance();
        from.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        inputdataControllerSecond.setText(dateFormatter.format(from.getTime()));
    }
}
```